# Save base64 images with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, canvas, base64, paperclip

I'm currently working on application for saving base64-encoded image as normal png image. I have following code in my controller's create action:

```
if @campaign.save
      unless params[:campaign][:design_attributes][:front_svg].empty?
        data =  params[:campaign][:design_attributes][:front_svg]
        File.open(params[:campaign][:design_attributes][:img_front_file_name], 'wb') do |f|
          f.write(ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(data))
        end
        f = File.open(params[:campaign][:design_attributes][:img_front_file_name])
        @campaign.design.img_front = f
      end
end
```

`front_svg` params contains base64 data. When I try to call action, I get following error:

`no implicit conversion of nil into String`

How do I save base64 encoded image using paperclip?

Comment: can you post your params[:campaign][:design_attributes] value here?

Answer (score 0):

Change `f.write` like this,

```
decoded_data = ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(data)
f.write(StringIO.new(decoded_data))
```

Comment: I followed your approach and got previously mentioned error on this line:
`File.open(params[:campaign][:design_attributes][:img_front_file_name], 'wb') do |f|`